# What's a less bad way to write this hex formatting function in Python?

Tags: python

With Python, I wanted to format a string of hex characters:

- spaces between each byte (easy enough): `2f2f` -> `2f 2f`
- line breaks at a specified max byte width (not hard): `2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f\n`
- address ranges for each line (doable): `0x7f8-0x808: 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f\n`
- replace large ranges of sequential `00` bytes with: `... trimmed 35 x 00 bytes [0x7 - 0x2a] ...` ... it was at this point that I knew I was doing some bad coding. The function got bloated and hard to follow. Too many features piled up in a non-intuitive way.

Example output:

```
0x0-0x10:   5a b6 f7 6e 7c 65 45 a0 bc 6a e5 f5 77 2b 92 48 
0x10-0x20:  47 d7 33 ea 40 15 44 ac 6b a4 50 78 6e f2 10 d4 
0x20-0x30:  9c 7c c1 f7 5a bf ec 9f b0 2b b7 29 97 ee 56 31 
0x30-0x40:  ff 23 d9 1a 0b 4e fd 65 50 92 42 eb b2 77 7a 55 
0x40-0x50:
```

I'm pretty sure the address ranges aren't correct anymore in certain cases (particularly when the `00` replacement occurs), the function just looks disgusting, and I'm embarrassed to even show it.

```
def pretty_print_hex(hex_str, byte_width=16, line_start=False, addr=0):
    out = ''
    condense_min = 12
    total_bytes = int(len(hex_str) / 2)
    line_width = False
    if byte_width is not False:
        line_width = byte_width * 2
    if line_start is not False:
        out += line_start
    end = addr + byte_width
    if (end > addr + total_bytes):
        end = addr + total_bytes
    out += f"{hex(addr)}-{hex(end)}:\t"
    addr += byte_width
    i = 0
    if len(hex_str) == 1:
        print('Cannot pretty print < 1 byte', hex_str)
        return
    condensing = False
    cond_start_addr = 0
    cond_end_addr = 0
    condense_cache = []
    while i < len(hex_str):
        byte = hex_str[i] + hex_str[i + 1]
        i += 2
        if byte == '00':
            condensing = True
            cond_start_addr = (addr - byte_width) + ((i + 1) % byte_width)
            condense_cache.append(byte)
        else:
            if condensing is True:
                condensed_count = len(condense_cache)
                if condensed_count >= condense_min:
                    cond_end_addr = cond_start_addr + condensed_count
                    out += f"... trimmed {condensed_count} x 00 bytes [{hex(cond_start_addr)} - {hex(cond_end_addr)}] ..."
                else:
                    for byte in condense_cache:
                        out += f"{byte} "
            condense_cache = []
            condensing = False
        if condensing is False:
            out += byte + ' '
            if (line_width is not False) and (i) % line_width == 0:
                out += '\n'
                if line_start is not False:
                    out += line_start
                    end = addr + byte_width
                    if end > addr + total_bytes:
                        end = addr + total_bytes
                if (addr - end) != 0:
                    out += f"{hex(addr)}-{hex(end)}:\t"
                    addr += byte_width
    if condensing is True:
        condensed_count = len(condense_cache)
        if condensed_count >= condense_min:
            cond_end_addr = cond_start_addr + condensed_count
            out += f"... trimmed {condensed_count} x 00 bytes [{hex(cond_start_addr)} - {hex(cond_end_addr)}] ..."
        else:
            for byte in condense_cache:
                out += f"{byte} "
    return out.rstrip()
```

example input / output:

```
hex_str = 'c8d8fb631cc7d072b62aaf9cd47bc270d4341e35f23b7a94acf24f33397a6cb4145b6eacfd56653d79bea10d2842023155e5b14bec3b5851a0a58cb3a523c476b126486e1392bdd2e3bcb6cbc333b23de387ae8624123009'
byte_width=16
line_start='\t'
addr=0

print(pretty_print_hex(hex_str , byte_width=16, line_start='\t', addr=0))

    0x0-0x10:   c8 d8 fb 63 1c c7 d0 72 b6 2a af 9c d4 7b c2 70 
    0x10-0x20:  d4 34 1e 35 f2 3b 7a 94 ac f2 4f 33 39 7a 6c b4 
    0x20-0x30:  14 5b 6e ac fd 56 65 3d 79 be a1 0d 28 42 02 31 
    0x30-0x40:  55 e5 b1 4b ec 3b 58 51 a0 a5 8c b3 a5 23 c4 76 
    0x40-0x50:  b1 26 48 6e 13 92 bd d2 e3 bc b6 cb c3 33 b2 3d 
    0x50-0x60:  e3 87 ae 86 24 12 30 09
```

It gets much worse when you involve some `00` replacement, here's an example of that:

```
hex_str = 'c8000000000000000000000000000aaf9cd47bc270d4341e35f23b7a94acf24f33397a6cb4145b6eacfd56653d79bea10d2842023155e5b14bec3b5851a0a58cb3a523c476b126486e1392bdd2e3bcb6cbc333b23de387ae8624123009'
byte_width=16
line_start='\t'
addr=0
print(pretty_print_hex(hex_str, byte_width=16, line_start='\t', addr=0))

    0x0-0x10:   c8 ... trimmed 13 x 00 bytes [0xd - 0x1a] ...0a af 
    0x10-0x20:  9c d4 7b c2 70 d4 34 1e 35 f2 3b 7a 94 ac f2 4f 
    0x20-0x30:  33 39 7a 6c b4 14 5b 6e ac fd 56 65 3d 79 be a1 
    0x30-0x40:  0d 28 42 02 31 55 e5 b1 4b ec 3b 58 51 a0 a5 8c 
    0x40-0x50:  b3 a5 23 c4 76 b1 26 48 6e 13 92 bd d2 e3 bc b6 
    0x50-0x60:  cb c3 33 b2 3d e3 87 ae 86 24 12 30 09
```

It would also make more sense to make the address range (`0x0-0x10) portray the true range, to include the trimmed bytes on that line, but I couldn't even begin to think of how to add that in.

Rather than patch this bad looking function, I thought I might ask for a better approach entirely, if one exists.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? An input and expected output for this big function would be very helpful.

Comment: @ljmc done! forgot my SO etiquette, ty.

Comment: Why not do the trimming *only* when it concerns 00 that would occur in output lines with only 00? That way you don't print that "trimmed" message halfway a line, but only use it for consecutive *lines* that *only* have 00. This will make the output more readable. And it will be easier to code nicely.

Comment: @trincot good idea, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to not start a "trimmed 00 bytes" series in the middle of an output line, but only apply this compacting when it applies to *complete* output lines with only zeroes.

This means that you will still see non-compacted zeroes in a line that also contains non-zeroes, but in my opinion this results in a cleaner output format. For instance, if a line would end with just two 00 bytes, it really does not help to replace that last part of the line with the longer "trimmed 2 x 00 bytes" message. By only replacing complete 00-lines with this message, and compress multiple such lines with one message, the output format seems cleaner.

To produce that output format, I would use the power of regular expressions:

1. to identify a block of bytes to be output on one line: either a line with at least one non-zero, or a range of zero bytes which either runs to the end of the input, or else is a multiple of the "byte width" argument.
2. to insert spaces in a line of bytes

All this can be done through iterations in one expression:

```
def pretty_print_hex(hex_str, byte_width=16, line_start='\t', addr=0):
    return "\n".join(f"{hex(start)}-{hex(last)}:{line_start}{line}" 
        for start, last, line in (
            (match.start() // 2, match.end() // 2 - 1,
                f"...trimmed {(match.end() - match.start()) // 2} x 00 bytes..." if match[1]
                else re.sub("(..)(?!$)", r"\1 ", match[0])
            )
            for match in re.finditer(
                f"(0+$|(?:(?:00){{{byte_width}}})+)|(?:..){{1,{byte_width}}}",
                hex_str
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: You are a magician. SO FEW LINES. I'm in disbelief that my giant monster of a function could be written this nicely, and improved no less.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it rather than write it (not sure - tell me to delete if required), you can use the excellent (I am not associated with it) hexdump:

https://pypi.org/project/hexdump

```py
python -m hexdump binary.dat
```

It is super cool - I guess you could also inspect the source for ideas.

It doesn't, however, look like it is still maintained...

Comment: This is quite nice actually, ty. It doesn't quite seem to have the features I fully wanted, but definitely leave it since I'm sure others would use this instead.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the challenge in this function, and this is what I could come up with this evening. It is somewhat shorter than your original one, but not as short as trincot's answer.

```py
def hexpprint(
    hexstring: str,
    width: int = 16,
    hexsep: str = " ",
    addr: bool = False,
    addrstart: int = 0,
    linestart: str = "",
    compress: bool = False,
):
    # if address get hex address length size
    if addr:
        addrlen = len(f"{addrstart+len(hexstring):x}")
    # compression buffer just count hex 0 chars
    cbuf = 0
    for i in range(0, len(hexstring), width):
        j = i + width
        row = hexstring[i:j]
        # if using compression and compressable
        if compress and row.count("0") == len(row):
            cbuf += len(row)
            continue
        # if not compressable and has cbuf, flush it
        if cbuf:
            line = linestart
            if addr:
                beg = f"0x{addrstart+i-cbuf:0{addrlen}x}"
                end = f"0x{addrstart+i:0{addrlen}x}"
                line += f"{beg}-{end} "
            line += f"compressed {cbuf//2} NULL bytes"
            print(line)
            cbuf = 0
        # print formatted hex row
        line = linestart
        if addr:
            beg = f"0x{addrstart+i:0{addrlen}x}"
            end = f"0x{addrstart+i+len(row):0{addrlen}x}"
            line += f"{beg}-{end} "
        line += hexsep.join(row[i : i + 2] for i in range(0, width, 2))
        print(line)
    # flush cbuf if necessary
    if cbuf:
        line = linestart
        if addr:
            beg = f"0x{addrstart+i-cbuf:0{addrlen}x}"
            end = f"0x{addrstart+len(hexstring):0{addrlen}x}"
            line += f"{beg}-{end} "
        line += f"compressed {cbuf//2} NULL bytes"
        print(line)
```

PS: I don't really like the code repetition to print things, so I might come back and edit later.

Comment: Later when I have a moment, or when you update it, I'll benchmark this against @trincot's. Not that logging is typically something I think of as needing to run fast, but hey if two versions of a function map the same input to output, how else does one compare? Well, on second thought, readability does have concrete value. But then again shorter doesn't always mean more readable.